# passing variadic arguments to 'print' doesn't produce desired output

Tags: swift

I'm writing a LogUtil class, which simply pass arguments to 'print' functions with extra information like "filename, line NO. " etc. see below codes.

However, usually when we use 'print' function to output like this:

```
  print("param1", "param2")
```

it outputs:

```
  param1 param2
```

however, use my LogUtil to log,

```
 LogUtil.d("tag", "param1", "param2"),
```

it outputs:

```
D - /LogUtil.swift(44): [["tag", "param1", "param2"]]
```

I want to output the original 'print' style:

```
D -/LogUtil.swift(44): tag param1 param2
```

how to fix this?Thanks!

```
class func p(level: LogLevel, items: Any...) {
    //todo eric thread id
    //todo eric fileName is too long
    //todo eric loglevel control
    //todo eric outputs to file


    let filePath = __FILE__
    let lineNo = __LINE__
    print("\(getLogLevelDesc(level)) - \(filePath)(\(lineNo)):", items)

}

class func d(items: Any...) {
    return p(LogLevel.DEBUG, items: items)
}

class func i(items: Any...) {
    return p(LogLevel.INFO, items: items)
}

class func w(items: Any...) {
    return p(LogLevel.WARN, items: items)
}

class func e(items: Any...) {
    return p(LogLevel.ERROR, items: items)
}

class func fatal(items: Any...) {
    return p(LogLevel.FATAL, items: items)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you call `LogUtil.d("tag", "param1", "param2")`. Since the `items` parameter is declared as variadic `Any...`, the local variable `items` inside `d` has type `[Any]`, and has the value `["tag", "param1", "param2"]`.

Then `d` calls `p`, passing its own `items` as the **first** argument for `p`'s `items` parameter. Since `p`'s `items` parameter is also variadic, `d` *could* pass more arguments for `p`'s `items`. That is, `d` *could* call `p(LogLevel.DEBUG, items: items, "more", "words")`. It doesn't, but it could.

Since `p`'s `items` parameter is variadic `Any...`, the local variable `items` inside `p` is also of type `[Any]`, and its value is `[["tag", "param1", "param2"]]`. It is an array of three elements inside an array of one element.

What you need to do is make `p`, or some new function, take a **non**-variadic `items` parameter, and call that from `d` and all your other variadic functions.

Also, `__FILE__` and `__LINE___` are deprecated. If you've upgraded to Xcode 7.3, you should use the new `#file` and `#line` special forms instead.

But you still have a problem: `#file` and `#line` will return the file and line where they are used **inside function `p`**. That's probably not what you want. You probably want the file and line where the program calls `d` or `i` or whatever.

To do that, you pass the file and line arguments to `d` (and the other functions), with default values of `#file` and `#line`. The defaults will be expanded at the call site, so you'll get the file and line number of the call to `d` or `i` or whatever.

So ultimately you want one function that knows how to take an `[Any]` (with only **one** level of array wrapping) and turn it into a space-separated string. Here's how you do that:

```
struct LogUtil {

    enum LogLevel: String {
        case Debug
        case Info
        case Warning
        case Error
        case Fatal
    }

    // The low-level function that all the others call.
    private static func log(level level: LogLevel, file: String, line: Int, items: [Any]) {
        let itemString = items.map { “\($0)” }.joinWithSeparator(" ")
        print("\(level) - \(file)(\(line)): \(itemString)")
    }
```

Note that `log(level:file:line:items:)` is **not variadic**, so it won't add another array wrapper around its `items`.

Then you define all your user-visible functions to call the `log` function:

```
    static func p(level: LogLevel, items: Any..., file: String = #file, line: Int = #line) {
        log(level: level, file: file, line: line, items: items)
    }

    static func d(items: Any..., file: String = #file, line: Int = #line) {
        log(level: .Debug, file: file, line: line, items: items)
    }

    static func i(items: Any..., file: String = #file, line: Int = #line) {
        log(level: .Info, file: file, line: line, items: items)
    }

    // other level-specific functions here...

}
```

When you call `LogUtil.d("tag", "foo", "bar")`, the output looks like you want:

```
Debug - /var/folders/kn/<snip>/playground282.swift(33): tag foo bar
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Now I totally understand it. Thanks again for the __FILE__ && __LINE__ bug and the new knowledge.

Comment: String($0) -> string cannot be initialized with Any

Comment: I guess that changed in the last seven years. I’ve updated my answer to use `”\($0)”` instead.